# How to customize JSON encoding output in Go?

Tags: json, go

I want to customize encoding format of a struct but got error: 
json: error calling MarshalJSON for type main.Info: invalid character 'o' in literal false (expecting 'a')
What's wrong with my code?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Info struct {
    name string
    flag bool
}

func (i Info) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.Write([]byte(i.name))
    if i.flag {
        b.Write([]byte(`"true"`))
    } else {
        b.Write([]byte(`"false"`))
    }   
    return b.Bytes(), nil 
}

func main() {
    a := []Info{
        {"foo", true},
        {"bar", false},
    }   
    out, err := json.Marshal(a)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf(string(out))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code produces invalid JSON text.

You should write the names of the fields too, and for safety quote both the field names and `string` values **but** don't quote `bool` values (else the Go `json` package will not unmarshal it into `bool` for example). Also enclose your values in brackets `{}` like this:

```
b.Write([]byte(`{"name":"`))       // started with {
b.Write([]byte(i.name))
b.Write([]byte(`","flag":`))       // note the , between values
if i.flag {
    b.Write([]byte(`true`))        // don't quote boolean value
} else {
    b.Write([]byte(`false`))       // don't quote boolean value
}
b.Write([]byte(`}`))               // must close with }
```

**Output** (try the complete application on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/G6-W8ynpJr)):

```
[{"name":"foo","flag":true},{"name":"bar","flag":false}]
```

But since you're not doing anything special during marshal, just export the fields (by starting them with upper-case letters) and the `json` package will marshal/unmarshal it for you automatically:

```
type Info struct {
    Name string
    Flag bool
}
```

Try this version on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/_cebFKFKcw).

**Output** (note the upper-cased names `"Name"` and `"Flag"`):

```
[{"Name":"foo","Flag":true},{"Name":"bar","Flag":false}]
```

You can also use tags if you want to use different names in the JSON text like this:

```
type Info struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Flag bool   `json:"flag"`
}
```

This will again produce an output with lower-cased names:

```
[{"name":"foo","flag":true},{"name":"bar","flag":false}]
```

Read the documentation of the [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) function to see what other options and customizations you can do with struct tags.

Comment: Oh, I've thought that I could Marshal out whatever I want even illegal JSON text

Comment: @Meng That is not called JSON marshaling, that is called generating _any_ binary/text content.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own strings to a buffer kind of eliminates the purpose of `json.Marshal()`. Maybe something like:

```
type Info struct {
    Name string `json:"name"` // Struct fields should have capital first letter
                              // if you want it to be found by the marshaller.
    Flag bool `json:"flag"`   // json:"flag" assigns the object key in json format
}
```

And then something like:

```
myInfo := Info {
    Name: "Foo",
    Flag: true,
}
slc, _ := json.Marshal(myInfo)
fmt.Println(string(slc))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're expecting a lot to magically happen for you within your implementation of `MarshalJSON`. Unfortunately you need to look at it as though you're building the string entirely from scratch. Meaning this;

```
func (i Info) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.Write([]byte(i.name))
    if i.flag {
        b.Write([]byte(`"true"`))
    } else {
        b.Write([]byte(`"false"`))
    }   
    return b.Bytes(), nil 
}
```

Needs to look more like this;

```
func (i Info) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.Write([]byte(`{"name":"`))       
    b.Write([]byte(i.name))
    b.Write([]byte(`","flag":`))        
    if i.flag {
        b.Write([]byte(`"true"`))        
    } else {
       b.Write([]byte(`"false"`))       
    }
    b.Write([]byte(`}`))
}
```

Also, I'm assuming you legitimately want a string for the boolean values (otherwise why implement this method at all, right?), if not then you'll want to get rid of the if and just use `b.Write([]byte(i.flag))`.